# load a file knowing Only the beginning of the name

Tags: matlab, search, namespaces, xls

I need to specify a filename for the function sftp_get() to download a file from a server using FTP.

The real filename is: ABCS_170230332211.csv

but I only know this part: ABCS_170230

I have tried to use:

`sftp_get(s_conn,dir('f1719-20170125*.csv'))` but this does not work.

any other suggestions?

Comment: `dir` [allows you to specify wildcards](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html#buscvwz-1) using `*`. `dir('ABCS_170230*.xls')`, for example.

Comment: Ok, in my case this does not work. It is maybe because I am actually trying to load a file from a sftp server. Let me then update my question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `dir` with wildcards `*`

```
dir('C:\Users\Data\ABCS_170230*.xls')
% >> ans = 'ABCS_170230332211.xls'
```

You may find `pwd` useful for getting the current directory if that is where your file is stored.

Also you can create strings from merging other strings using array notation:

```
myFile = 'ABCS_';
myDate = 170230;
myDir = [pwd, '\Data\', myFile, str2num(myDate), '*.xls'];
% myDir = 'C:\Users\UserName\MatlabDevelopment\Data\ABCS_170230*.xls'
% Where MatlabDevelopment is a stand-in for your current Matlab folder

dir(myDir)
% >> ans = 'ABCS_170230332211.xls'
```

Comment: Using strict string concatenation to build filepaths is a bad idea. Use [`fullfile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html).

Comment: @excaza "bad idea" surely depends what you're doing with it and how robust your file system is...

Comment: It's a bad idea not to respect the file system's path syntax, period.